# Convert string to Instant in Java

Tags: java

I am quite new to java .I want to convert string in format "1558337076000+0000" to Instant.
I have tried `Instant.parse("1558337076000+0000")` but this throws a exception .Can i get some help here?

Comment: Strip off the `+0000`, parse the number as a long.

Comment: Well, what does the exception say?

Comment: "...text string such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.00Z.The string must represent a valid instant in UTC and is parsed using DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT." - from [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the Javadoc, the String you pass in must meet a certain requirement

> The string must represent a valid instant in UTC and is parsed using DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.

The example given for DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT is `2011-12-03T10:15:30Z`.

I can't tell by looking at your String (it's 3am here right now...) if that's millis or seconds, but I'd recommend using `ofEpochMilli` or `ofEpochSecond` as appropriate. You would first need to covert the String to a long with `Long.parseLong()` which would involve removing the trailing `+0000` since that is not valid `Long` formatting.